# Rails wiil_paginate and Ransack error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, will-paginate, ransack

```
Rails 5.0.1
Ransack Gem 1.8.2
Will_paginate 3.1.5
```

I'm trying to paginate the search results in my Rails app; both the search works fine, but I cannot get to the second page of the results without this error:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

  def show
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.where(post_id: @post.id).order("created_at ASC")
  end

  def edit

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:26:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"page"=>"2", "id"=>"search"}
```

Which is weird, but the error is thrown on an action that isn't even the page I'm on. It's in "show", but I"m in "index" and the comments aren't even shown on the index.

Here's my controller for the two:

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.where(post_id: @post.id).order("created_at ASC")
  end

  def index #this needs to be fixed so that Posts can paginate properly
    if params[:tag]
      @search = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag]).search(params[:q])
      @posts = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
    elsif params[:q].blank?
      @search = Post.search(params[:q])
      @posts = @search.result(distinct: true).includes(:tags).all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
    else 
      @search = Post.search(params[:q])
      @posts = @search.result.includes(:tags).all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)

    end
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
So the problem seems to be that my app is trying to serve posts#show for the url `http://localhost:3000/posts/search?page=2` and passing in the search params into it.

This is the relevant routs:

```
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      match 'search' => 'posts#index', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
    end

    resources :comments
  end
```

Don't know why this is happening...

Answer (score 1):

So.. It was kinda a routes thing, but I was also using the advanced Ransack setup instead of the simple one; it was using the search parameters as a collection under the posts, and it got all messed up from there.